# IDisposable Singleton with StructureMap 4 & NestedContainer

Tags: c#, singleton, idisposable, structuremap4

I'm looking to register an EasyNetQ's `IBus` which implements `IDisposable` as a singleton with StructureMap.
The issue is when using nested container, the instance is disposed with the container, thus leaving me with a singleton instance being disposed for every other containers.

```
For<IBus>()
    .Use(c => BusBuilder.CreateMessageBus())
    .Singleton();
```

`ContainerScoped` is not an option here as I need that is kept alive during all the application lifespan.

How do I prevent StructureMap from disposing this instance with nested containers ? How do I tell it to dispose the instance only with the root container ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I knew something was odd with my issue. What was the point of defining singletons if they were disposed with each container ?

Indeed, StructureMap does not dispose singleton objects unless a root container is being disposed, see [the PipelineGrap.cs source code.](https://github.com/structuremap/structuremap/blob/master/src/StructureMap/PipelineGraph.cs#L139) :

```
if (Role == ContainerRole.Root)
{
    _profiles.AllProfiles().Each(x => x.Dispose());
}
```

It turned out that my `IBus` instance was being manually disposed by some mysterious legacy code in which it was injected.

Anyway, for anyone facing the same issue : *track down your call to `Dispose` as StructureMap is doing its job as you though it would :)*